# JavaScript: Is it possible to pass a variable into a callback function that is assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax

A lot of people say that this is asked too much in the comments, which made me hesitant to ask this, but I still have not found a solution in their answers, mostly because (1) they are typically using jQuery and (2) the questions usually contain technicalities I do not understand.

I have a function with a variable inside. The variable is assigned a function. I'm sure this concept is not exclusive to AJAX, but that is the context I am using it in, if it makes a difference.

```
function iClick(this)
{
    var foo = "I would like to pass this.";

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function (foo) { alert(foo); }
}
```

I want to pass a variable into the function. However, since there is no original function declaration, how do I specify parameters? Can I even do that?

Comment: +1. I say ask if you've searched but haven't found what you're looking for. A lot of us come from non-programming backgrounds so some computer science nuances and even fundamentals often need clarification (at least in my case).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just don't declare that variable as a parameter in your anonymous function, like this:

```
function iClick(this)
{
    var foo = "I would like to pass this.";
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () { alert(foo); }
}
```

When you call the first parameter `foo` it's whatever's *calling* that callback passes in that's `foo` inside the function.  If you want to reference a previously declared variable just do that, make sure *not* to use a parameter with the same name.

Comment: Oh! I thought it would be out of it's scope. Thanks!

Comment: @Tarik - JS has function scope and closures. Functions have access to the variables in parent scopes even after parent functions have returned.

Comment: @PeterAjtai   What if inside ajax.onreadystatechage I want to assign a new value to foo. Would that be visible in iClick() ? e.g.

    function iClick(this)
    {
    var foo = "I would like to pass this.";
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () { foo = "Value changed"; }
    console.log(foo); // would this print 'Value changed' ?
    }

Comment: @Ali - No, because the `console.log(foo)` would get triggered immediately after `ajax.onreadystatechange = ...`, but the `onreadystatechange` itself would only get triggered at some future point in time........... so, it's all the same `foo`, but you have to consider the timing.

Comment: Doesn't work: The variable stays available to the callback, but isn't save from being modified. Calling more than one callback won't work: https://jsfiddle.net/h5Loenfk/

Answer (score 19):

You can create a function like this

```
var c="hello";

(function(b){
   alert(b) 
})(c);
```

result would be "hello"

Comment: that's the answer, and this is really useful when you want to parse a variable from outside into an async callback like `db.query` in node for instance

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira  Very simple to test. strange that you ask?  But to answer.  The c variable would the one that is in scope, which is the local version to the function.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira  Here is a simple test.  https://jsfiddle.net/qon4cwhn/   You will see the the value of c as a global is not modified.

Comment: very stupid question indeed :) Of course!!! the function is anonymously defined and immediately run, having the value of `c` parsed into the function local variable `b`

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this, but maybe it's not necessary:

```
function iClick(this)
{
    var foo = "I would like to pass this.";

    ajax.onreadystatechange = (function(thevar) {
        return function () { alert(thevar); };
      })(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @John Hartsock referred, the answer that everyone should really remember is this

```
var c="hello";

(function(b){
   alert(b) 
})(c);
```

And that's very important for example in a `for` loop when there is some async function inside it, because otherwise you don't get the correct item.

Tell me, what comes out from here?

```js
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log(i); 
    }, 1000);
}
```

Exactly: all 5, because when all the timers are triggered after 1 second, variable `i` is already at the value `5`.

But if you use a **self-invoked anonymous function** (SIAF) like this

```js
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  (function (j){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      console.log(j); 
      }, 1000);
   })(i);
}
```

it does work, since every time the function is evoked, it runs another instance of the function and as any function, it has its own local variables. I do not merely define the function, I also run it right away (through the `();` at the end), but then internally a new instance of the function will be created with different internal local variables, as I parse to the function a different variable every time I run it.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you wanted something like that

```
function handleAjaxRequest(params) {
    var context = {'b':'inner', 'c': params['c']};
    function rendered(html) {
      // render
    }
    function gotPart(part) {
        context['a'] = part;
        engine.render(context).addCallback(rendered);
    }
    ajax.getPart(params).addCallback(gotPart);
}
```