# How to pass a variable to event listener function?

Tags: javascript

I'm having difficulties removing an event listener, since `removeEventListener` only works for non-anynomous functions I need to make a named function. The problem is I can't figure out how to pass the `chart` variable to the `toggleLabels` function without calling the function while I do it..

I tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946177/javascript-is-it-possible-to-pass-a-variable-into-a-callback-function-that-is-a) but no answer worked.

Is this possible?

```
var chart = {}; // Big object 

labelToggle.addEventListener('click', toggleLabels);

function toggleLabels(chart) {

    scope.graph.isLabelsVisible = chart.isLabelsVisible = !chart.isLabelsVisible;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      chart.series[i].isLabelsVisible = !chart.series[i].isLabelsVisible;
      chart.series[i].hide();
      chart.series[i].show();
    };
  };
```

Comment: I usually use event listeners in the body of the html, and there, you can pass the arguments directly (`onclick='foo("toto")'` for example)

Comment: @HolyDanna That's horrible practice, and I can't do that unfortunately.

Comment: I know, but I try not to use much event listeners, any way. Maybe this post ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function#256763 ) can help you find a solution

Answer (score 1):

When passing parameters, you can use an "anonymous function" that calls the specified function with the parameters:

```
labelToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toggleLabels(chart);
});
```

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 7;
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
    myFunction(a, b);
});

function myFunction(x, y) {
    var result = x + y;
    console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click here!</button>
```

Comment: Does this allow unbinding of the event listener?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is to make toggleLabels a function of chart. For example:

```
function chart(series) {
    this.series = series;  
    this.toggleLabels = function (name) {
    for (i = 0; i < lthis.series.ength; i++) {
      chart.series[i].isLabelsVisible = !this.series[i].isLabelsVisible;
      this.series[i].hide();
      this.series[i].show();
    };
    };
}
```

And then just operate on the `chart` object like this:

```
chart.series
chart.toggleLabels()
```

And then, you should be able to do the following:

```
 labelToggle.addEventListener('click', chart.toggleLabels);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a function like this:

```
var chart = {}; // Big object 

labelToggle.addEventListener('click', toggleLabels(chart));

function toggleLabelsCls(chart) {

    return function(chart) {
       scope.graph.isLabelsVisible = chart.isLabelsVisible = !chart.isLabelsVisible;

       for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         chart.series[i].isLabelsVisible = !chart.series[i].isLabelsVisible;
         chart.series[i].hide();
         chart.series[i].show();
       };
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using [partial application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
labelToggle.addEventListener('click', toggleLabels.bind(this,chart));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the shortest solution:

```
labelToggle.addEventListener('click', function(){toggleLabels(chart)});
```

Comment: It's not global, it was just an example. It gets passed to an outer function.

Comment: Oh, I see @Kld already answered like I am did. His solution is right.